# python stripping text and definition of names

Tags: python, text, return, screen-scraping, strip

I am **scraping** car name and car price from a car site to subsequently append into a table which could be saved to an excel file. I need help to strip all codes except for the car name details, and to overcome this 'names not defined' problem.The following are the codes

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
import pandas as pd
headers = ({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit\
/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'})
base_url =   "https://www.carlist.my/used-cars-for-sale/malaysia"
response = get(base_url, headers=headers)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(html_soup)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
content_list = html_soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'grid__item'})
print(content_list)
basic_info = []
for item in content_list:
    basic_info.append(item.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'ellipsize js-ellipsize-text'}))
print(basic_info)
def get_names(basic_info):
    names = []
    for item in basic_info:
        for i in item:
            names.append(i.find_all('a', attrs = {'class' : '"ellipsize js-ellipsize-text'})
```

[0].text.strip())
return names

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : names})[['Name']]
data.head()
data.drop_duplicates().to_excel('Car_list.xls')

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-e2eba5476dff> in <module>
      6     return names
      7 
----> 8 data = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : names})[['Name']]
      9 data.head()
     10 data.drop_duplicates().to_excel('Car_list.xls')

NameError: name 'names' is not defined
```

Comment: The error you shared is not an error in the code you shared above, please share an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: From what I can tell, ```names``` is being defined inside ```get_names```, but you are trying to access it in your ```ipython``` terminal, therefore ```names``` is undefined in that context.